# Ruby If Statements

Tags: ruby, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements, bubble-sort

```
def bubble_sort(array)
    swaps = 0;
    i = 0;
    last = array.length - 1

    while swaps > -1 
        if i == last
            i = 0
            last--
            swaps = 0

            if swaps < 1
                swaps = -1
            end
        end

        if array[i] > array[i+1]
            temp = array[i]
            array[i] = array[i+1]
            array[i+1] = temp
            swaps++
        end
        i++
    end
end
```

What is wrong with this code? No logical errors, but  I'm getting these syntactical errors, and can't figure out why.

> bubble_sort.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
>
> bubble_sort.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. Fix that and the problem will become more apparent. As a note, `i++` and `i--` is **not** valid Ruby as it does not have `++` or `--`. You should also avoid putting in pointless `;` delimiters.

Comment: What's that `end` after your first block of code?

Comment: It's for the function that isn't properly indented.

Comment: The syntax errors go away with `++` replaced by `+= 1`, and `--` with `-= 1`. The logical errors remain.

Comment: I would really like to know which Ruby tutorial teaches this stuff. I mean, where do people get the idea that `i++` is even legal in Ruby? It's not mentioned in the documentation (obviously, since it isn't legal), it's not mentioned in any book I know of, it is not mentioned in any tutorial I know of, the fact that one gets a syntax error should also be a strong hint that it doesn't exist, there are literally dozens of questions here on [so] explaining that it doesn't exist … so who tells people otherwise?

Comment: thanks guys, I was able to fix both the syntax and errors! and @JörgWMittag the error was a honest mistake using syntax from other languages I've used I don't know why I did it it went over my head.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: My guess is that this code has been literally translated from another language, possibly Java or pseudo-language.

Answer (score 0):

Your code with proper ruby syntax will look like this.

```
def bubble_sort(array)
    swaps = 0
    i = 0
    last = array.length - 1

    while swaps > -1 
        if i == last
            i = 0
            last -= 1
            swaps = 0

            if swaps < 1
                swaps = -1
            end
        end

        if array[i] > array[i+1]
            temp = array[i]
            array[i] = array[i+1]
            array[i+1] = temp
            swaps += 1
        end 
        i += 1
    end
end
```

I didn't tried to change your logic. Only syntax is changed. And I think you should return array at the end. Otherwise output will be nil. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid Ruby syntax:

```
i++
```

Change it to:

```
i += 1
```

Similarly, change this:

```
swaps++
```

To this:

```
swaps += 1
```